# Parse post data with punctuation incorrectly in golang

Tags: c, post, go

I know how to parse post data in golang

```
r.ParseForm()
pid := r.PostFormValue("pid")
code := r.PostFormValue("code")
lang := r.PostFormValue("lang")
author := r.PostFormValue("author")
```

But the post data is `pid=1&code=#include <stdio.h>\x0Aint main()\x0A{\x0A\x09printf(\x223\x5Cn\x22);\x0A\x09return 0;\x0A}&lang=c&author=11`(this is obtained from nginx log)

So when I parse the data, it could be wrong. The parsed data of `code` is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("3\n")
```

instead of

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("3\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the raw code, which could be **unsafe**, your problem is because of this:

https://golang.org/src/net/url/url.go?s=21047:21092#L761

[image]

I would suggest that you base64encode your log code and then decode it in your handler.

```go
import "encoding/base64"

...

code, err := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(r.PostFormValue("code"))
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
```

Then your request should look like this:

```
curl --data "pid=1&code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHN0ZGlvLmg-XHgwQWludCBtYWluKClceDBBe1x4MEFceDA5cHJpbnRmKFx4MjIzXHg1Q25ceDIyKTtceDBBXHgwOXJldHVybiAwO1x4MEF9&lang=c&author=11" http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: The full problem isn't because of that particular line in the current go query handling code, the problem is that there is a limited character set that are safe for URLs, and a number of reserved characters within that set

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right, it's what I said in the first line of my answer, I just showed where and why passing that unsafe parameter causes the issue. Maybe it wasn't that clear, I'll highlight the unsafe word. Thanks for the comment @JimB